# Xcode Apple Watch project, local notification not being presented?

Tags: xcode, notifications, watchkit

I am trying to present a local notification on an Apple Watch simulator with a button. This is the code:

```
@IBAction func buttonOne() {

    print("button one pressed")

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Notified!", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "This is a notification appearing!", arguments: nil)

    // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5,
                                                    repeats: false)
    // Schedule the notification.
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Notify", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
        if let theError = error {
            print(theError.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("successful notification")
        }
    }

}
```

The console is successfully printing "successful notification," but the notification never appears on the watch simulator. I have no idea why this is

Answer (score 1):

1) Before scheduling a notification, request permissions. Use `requestAuthorization` method, for example:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    // Enable or disable features based on authorization
}
```

2) Notifications will not appear on watch face if the application is running in foreground. Considering this you may use **cmd + H** to hide the app.

Comment: 2) You can implement notification handling in the foreground as well. You just have to add this value to your notification content by `content.setValue(true, forKey: "shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground")` and have to make your class conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and implement the function `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert,.badge])
    }`